# Ubuntu 18.04 Google-earth launch problem

Tags: drivers, 18.04, launcher, google-earth

Having just installed 18.04 (upgraded from new 16.04 install) and google-earth. I can only launch Google-earth from, and runs in, the terminal, there is just a blank icon on the launchpad which can be 'locked to launcher' but subsequently will not work.
I have updated the NVidea graphics driver, this is the last of several problems. I have no idea what to do next, any ideas please.

GigaByte GA970A-DS3 with 8 core AMD, 16 GB and Gforce 8400 graphics

Comment: Do you have any error messages if you run Earth from terminal with `google-earth-pro` or `google-earth`? Please add them to the question if any.

Comment: No error messages, GE seems to run just fine, just the loading problem. I have been working on this since my post. Going back to my working 16.04 32 bit SSD, this is the same as if I open GE as a guest, GE runs OK but only from the terminal. I guess it is a simple configuration error, wrong permissions?

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved. In desperation I decided to look in the applications folder and found a 'google earth' link there. Opened the application from the folder and up came the launcher icon, all is now well. Only two years of trying to get GE 64 bit working!
Thank you for your time.